# Do we need a separate "appeal-to-pity" tag?

Tags: discussion

Several recent questions have been tagged "appeal to pity".

[Avis Rent-a-Car's slogan 'We're #2' : This is an Appeal to Pity?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/36116/avis-rent-a-cars-slogan-were-2-this-is-an-appeal-to-pity)

[Why is it an Appeal to Pity if a defense attorney evidences misfortune of the defendant?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/36115/why-is-it-an-appeal-to-pity-if-a-defense-attorney-evidences-misfortune-of-the-de)

[Did Clarence Darrow really Appeal to Pity?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/36114/did-clarence-darrow-really-appeal-to-pity)

[Please expose how Socrates subtly Appeals to Pity](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/36113/please-expose-how-socrates-subtly-appeals-to-pity)

Is this necessary or helpful?

Or does the more general fallacies tag suffice?

Comment: That's the result of one particular user whose MO is to study a small area in great depth, and then move on to new  once he's found satisfactory answers. I'd say the next time a question is asked about the AtP, by a different user, it's worth revisiting the need for a tag. For now, I'm not sure it's useful.

Comment: @DanBron That user would be I. Please tell me if there is something wrong that I `study a small area in great depth, and then move on to new once he's found satisfactory answers`. Am I overdoing anything?

Comment: @Timere No, nothing wrong with that at all (by my lights, anyway, but I'm mostly a passive user on this stack). I was just making the point that a tag is probably unwarranted until we see more (than one) users with a need for it. I infer you sometimes read it that way, but I have no issue with you or your questions.

Comment: @DanBron OK. Thanks. I ask because I am learning this on my own.

Answer (score 4):

The topic of fallacies is rather narrow and most questions we get are things like "what's this fallacy" or "is this a fallacy". The 'fallacies' tag definitely suffices for this, and I don't see any point in tagging specific types of fallacies.